# convert binary image data to base64 string from http response sent by FilePathResult ASP.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, base64, blob, filereader

An image file is sent from ASP.Net MVC using FilePathResult. How can this image be converted into a base64 string at client side (web browser) when http response is received. It is showing data in the raw form in response.data object. I've tried

```
var blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onloadend = function () {
     var base64data = reader.result;
     console.log(base64data);
}
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can use the image directly using the raw base64 image. ex: <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAA............" />

Comment: actually, I am misunderstanding with your question.

Comment: data: "����JFIF��C↵↵↵  ↵%# , #&')*)-0-(0%()(�................"

Comment: Above mentioned is the raw data received in response object. How can that be converted to base 64 string?

Comment: I think, this is great example for you: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201767/Load-Base-Images-using-jQuery-and-MVC

Comment: In https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201767/Load-Base-Images-using-jQuery-and-MVC base64 string is sent from server. While in my case, binary data is received from server and converted to base64 using javascript at client-end.

Comment: oh, do you need to convert the binary data using JS at the client?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

When you fetch the binary as text with ajax, browsers will try to parse the character set and change your data.

You must fetch the data as a blob to avoid to tell them not to

```
function getBase64(blob) {
  var blob = xhr.response
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
       var base64data = reader.result;
       console.log(base64data);
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', '/myfile.png', true)
xhr.responseType = 'blob'  // get data as blob
xhr.onload = function() {
  getBase64(xhr.response)
}
xhr.send()

// or if you are using fetch
fetch('/myfile.png')
  .then(function(res) {
    res.blob() // get data as blob
    .then(getBase64)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am not misunderstood:

Try this script, for the easier ajax I'm using jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'someImage.png',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(r) {
        var data = btoa(r);
        $('img.photo').attr('src', "data:image/png;base64," + data);
    },
});
```

you can change above code as you need.